# Commit only newly added files in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

I am having a number of modified and newly added files in my application. Is it possible to commit only the newly added files.

I know it is possible to use:

```
svn ci -m "Commit message" file_path_1 file_path_2
```

But when the number of files is more, this is not a proper solution.

Is there a single line command for this?

Answer (score 0):

`svn commit --targets ARG`, there ARG is file with additional filenames (can't recall: space-separated or EOL)